# Treeview control with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, treeview

I'm relatively new to C# / Entity Framework and am trying to get a Treeview control / HierachicalDataTemplate working with Entity Framework 4.0 and am missing something.

I have a self-referencing table:

> divid (PK, int, not null); divname (nchar(100), not null);
>   divshortname (nchar(50), not null); parentid (FK, int, null); orgid
>   (FK, int, not null)

I have loaded the table as 'orghierarchy' into entity framework and have named the many side of the self-relation 'child' and the single side 'parent'.

I create an ObservableCollection thus:

```
    private ObservableCollection<orghierarchy> _firstgeneration;
    public ObservableCollection<orghierarchy> FirstGeneration
    {
        get
        {
            if (OrgID != 0)
            {
                _firstgeneration = SetDivTree(OrgID);
            }
            return _firstgeneration;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _firstgeneration)
                _firstgeneration = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<orghierarchy> SetDivTree(int _orgid)
    {
        ObservableCollection<orghierarchy> _temp;
        using (var context = new IFREntities())
        {
            var divs = from orghierarchies in context.orghierarchies.Include("child")
                       where orghierarchies.orgid == _orgid & orghierarchies.parentid == null
                       orderby orghierarchies.divshortname
                       select orghierarchies;

            _temp = new ObservableCollection<orghierarchy>(divs);
        }
        return _temp;
    }
```

The ".Include" seems to bring all the children rows back with the query based on stepping through the code.

My XAML is

```
<TreeView x:Name="DivHierarchy" Margin="8" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}" >
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration.child}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding divname}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<TreeView.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BigCtrlBackground}"/>
</TreeView.Background>
```

My treeview is empty and I'm not sure what the issue might be.

Comment: Hey, @DeeDub84 -- did you ever get this working? If so I'd really benefit from the answer. Thanks a bunch :) Hope it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XAML excluding all the layout settings you want. You can do that yourself. :)

```
<TreeView x:Name="DivHierarchy" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RootTemplate}" />
```

Add the following to the Resources section, e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=child}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=divname}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootTemplate"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=child}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=divname}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I think it will work but you will also see child entries in the root level as well. Well! Try it.